# Connecting Android app to my database?

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

I have been trying to send data from my app to my local database with the help of a few tutorials off youtube. The program runs without errors but when I try to send data to my database nothing happens.
There must me something really silly that Im doing wrong unfortunately I have no experience with PHP and unable to solve it.Here is the code im trying to use.

ServerConnection method

```
 private void serverConnection() {
.
.
.

List<NameValuePair>  nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Lat",lat));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Long",log));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Number",svdNum));

    try{
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/tech/serverConnection.php");
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        is = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(ClientProtocolException e){
        Log.e("ClientProtocol", "Log_tag");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        Log.e("Log_tag", "IOException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

serverConnection.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect(localhost, 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('finalyearproject');
if(! $conn )
{
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$Number=$_POST['Number'];
$Latitude=$_POST['Lat'];
$Latitude=$_POST['Long'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO app_backup(Number,Latitude, Longitude) VALUES('$Number', '$Latitude', '$Longitude')";

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

Thank you in advance for any help! 
I have edited my php code a little it seems to work fine manually but when are try to send data from the emulator nothing happens.

logcat when I try to send the data to the database

04-03 06:11:40.908: W/Trace(868): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-03 06:11:59.691: D/ExchangeService(563): Received deviceId from Email app: null
04-03 06:11:59.691: D/ExchangeService(563): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
04-03 06:12:00.123: W/Trace(277): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
.
.
.
04-03 06:12:04.830: W/Trace(563): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-03 06:12:04.859: W/Trace(563): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-03 06:12:04.859: D/ExchangeService(563): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
04-03 06:12:04.911: W/Trace(563): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-03 06:12:04.911: W/Trace(563): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-03 06:12:04.911: D/ExchangeService(563): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
04-03 06:12:04.989: D/dalvikvm(277): GREF has increased to 601
04-03 06:12:04.989: W/ActivityManager(277): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
04-03 06:12:05.110: W/Trace(563): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-03 06:12:05.208: D/ExchangeService(563): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
04-03 06:12:05.269: W/Trace(563): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-03 06:12:05.299: W/Trace(563): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-03 06:12:05.381: E/ActivityThread(563): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cff480 that was originally bound here
04-03 06:12:05.381: E/ActivityThread(563): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cff480 that was originally bound here
04-03 06:12:05.381: E/ActivityThread(563):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:969)
04-03 06:12:05.381: E/ActivityThread(563):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
04-03 06:12:05.381: E/ActivityThread(563):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
04-03 06:12:05.381: E/ActivityThread(563):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
    04-03 06:12:05.381: E/ActivityThread(563):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)

Comment: take the query between the quotes in mysql_query() function and paste it phpmyadmin or a mysql console to see if there's any errors.

Comment: Watch out for the serious **SQL injection vulnerabilities** in this code - don't go live until it is fixed please!

Comment: @unixmiah I have changed the php code and done what you have asked it works fine now, but only when I query the function manually in phpmyadmin, when I try to do the same from the app it does not work.